# How do I declare a variable using its interface as a generic

Tags: kotlin

I'm converting some Java code to Kotlin, and I've run into some code that essentially works like the following:

```
interface Animal {}

class Dog : Animal {}

interface Leash<in T: Animal> {
    fun attachToCollarOf(animal: T)
}

class DogLeash : Leash<Dog> {
    override fun attachToCollarOf(animal: Dog) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

val foo: Leash<Animal> = DogLeash
```

When trying to assign `foo` with the given type to `DogLeash()`, I get the following error: `error: type mismatch: inferred type is DogLeash but Leash<Animal> was expected`. Is there some combination of `in`, `out` or `with` that will allow me to do the assignment on the final line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `in` makes types [contravariant](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#variance), so `DogLeash` is not a subtype of `Leash<Animal>`. A reference of type `Leash<Animal>` would allow you to call `attachToCollarOf` on any `Animal`, whereas `DogLeash` can only work with `Dog`s - the compiler rightfully disallows this assignment. Instead, if you had:

```
class AnimalLeash : Leash<Animal> {
    override fun attachToCollarOf(animal: Animal) {
        println("Attached to Animal")
    }
}
```

Then doing `val leash: Leash<Dog> = AnimalLeash()` would work: a reference to `Leash<Dog>` allows you to call `attachToCollarOf` on `Dog`s only, but any `AnimalLeash` works for a `Dog`.

Comment: If I don't make the types contravariant, is there a way for me to do this assignment? Declaring the `Leash` interface as:
```interface Leash<in T: Animal> {
    fun attachToCollarOf(animal: T)
}```

also gives me a type mismatch error.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here. You can't assign an instance of `DogLeash` to a reference of type `Leash<Animal>`, since that would allow you to call `attachToCollarOf` on `Animal`, whereas `DogLeash` only supports calling that method on `Dog`.

Comment: That comment made it click in my mind. Thanks for the explanation!